# "ng lint" adds a bunch of equals next to an ERRORED word

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

Whenever I run ng lint --fix, it detects a variable called "REFUND_ERRORED" and adds a bunch of "===========" next to it, breaking my code. How can i fix this?

```
            [class.fail]="
              item.data === 'CANCELLED' ||
              item.data === 'EXPIRED' ||
              item.data === 'RISKY' ||
              item.data == 'REFUND_ERRORED==========' ||
              item.status == 'fail'
       ==========     "
```

Comment: could you share a small snippet of your code before running `ng lint` and after?

Comment: there, added it to the post. Originally those two "========" are not present.

Comment: remove `--fix` if you don't want eslint helps modifying your src

Comment: i do want it to modify it, i just dont want the "======"